Is underlayment needed for stone composite vinyl flooring?
I am planning on installing SPC flooring throughout the house. I’ve run into an issue where I removed a wall between the kitchen and dining room and they originally had laminate floors in the kitchen with 1/4" board under it. I am wondering if the right way to do it is lay the 1/4 inch board throughout or rip up the board in the kitchen and lay it directly on the subfloor.

What does the manufacturer of your prospective SPC say about installation and required subflooring?

It says it can be installed directly on the subfloor as long as it’s clean and level

But what do they say about subfloor requirements, e.g. thickness, material?

They don’t give specifics on thickness of the subfloor but its 1/2 inch subfloor thats installed in the house. The 1/4 inch was used under the vinyl flooring as a buffer for imperfections which is pretty common.

What is your manufacturer?

According to Flooring Inc. buying guide.  SPC flooring is:
Great for uneven subfloors: Rigid core is designed to be installed over any existing hard surface, including tile, even if it’s imperfect or not completely level.
You should be ok with adding 1/4" or taking out the 1/4 in the kitchen.  Either should be ok. I'd do what is easier and gives the final floor height I need.   If you are in a cold climate the extra 1/4 board could make the floor a bit warmer.
